# Is good approach to combine Next.js with redux and apollo graphql?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm new in Next.js and GraphQL world. So far i've been using react with reduxjs and axios for API calls. I would learn more advanced stuff so here is my question. If i'm using apollo graphql what options do i have for local state management? It can be handled by apollo itself or i should use external tool like redux store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apollo at its heart is a GraphQL implementation that helps people manage their data. They also make and maintain a GraphQL client (Apollo Client) which we can use with React frameworks like Next.js.

The Apollo Client is a state management client that allows you to manage both local and remote data with GraphQL and you can use it to fetch, cache, and modify application data.

In this article, we’ll discuss why we should use the Apollo Client with Next.js and how we can use the Apollo Client with Next.js to render pages via the three rendering methods Next.js supports; static site generation (SSG), server-side rendering (SSR), and client-side rendering (CSR).

If you want to use your Redux and Apollo state in a component, you need to use both graphql from react-apollo and connect from react-redux. This will let you better track the different events that happen in your app, and how your client and server side data changes interleave.

## Why use Apollo Client with Next.js

First, let’s look at why we should use the Apollo Client with Next.js. There are three key reasons to use the Apollo Client:

1. Out-of-the-box support for caching
2. Built-in loading and error states
3. Declarative approach to data fetching

### Out-of-the-box support for caching

In Apollo’s own words, “Caching a graph is no easy task, but we’ve spent two years focused on solving it.”

Apollo has invested serious amounts of time in making their caching process the most efficient and effective they can. So, why try and reinvent the wheel? If you’re fetching data in your application and working with GraphQL, then the Apollo Client is a great way of handling your data.

Another benefit is that there is minimal setup required for developers using the client. Apollo even labels it as “zero-config.” We will see this in our application example further in the post, but to set up caching in an application, all we need to do is add the code below to our application:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

### Built-in loading and error states

The Apollo Client has a custom React Hook built into it called block useQuery, which we will use in our example application, and gives us built-in loading and error states for us to use.

While this doesn’t sound impressive, what it means for developers is that we don’t need to spend time implementing this logic ourselves, we can just take the booleans the Hook returns and change our application rendering as required.

Thanks to these built-in states, using the Apollo Client means we can spend less time worrying about implementing data fetching logic and focus on building our application.

### Declarative approach to data fetching

Another benefit of the way the Apollo Client implements the useQuery Hook is that data fetching with the Apollo Client is declarative rather than imperative.

What this means for us is we only need to tell Apollo what data we want and it gets it for us. We don’t need to write the logic and give it a list of step-by-step instructions on how to do it or handle it.

Once again, this is another great example of how the Apollo Client helps speed up development and make us more efficient developers when working with GraphQL.

You can learn more in this page right here if why use nextjs with apollo: [This link](https://blog.logrocket.com/why-use-next-js-apollo/)

---

By default, Apollo Client creates its own internal Redux store to manage queries and their results. If you are already using Redux for the rest of your app, you can have the client integrate with your existing store instead.

In simple words, When you're using Apollo, you shouldn't be putting that data into Redux. You can still use Redux for other things, but apollo's duty is to store that data and make it accessible to your components. Taking it out and putting it into Redux means doing double the work for no added gain, and there's a strong risk you'll introduce a lot of asynchrony between the two levels as a result.

Referenced from here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68348307/how-can-i-use-redux-and-graphql-with-apollo-client-in-the-same-react-app)

And learn more if u want to integrate redux and apollo from here: [enter link description here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/apollo-docs-1.x/redux.html)

Learn more if it is necessary to use redux with apollo right here as well: [enter link description here](https://leapgraph.com/graphql-redux-apollo/)